# What is the limit to the number of database connection controller services that can be configured on a single Apache NiFi instance?

Tags: jdbc, apache-nifi

I am using a `DBCPConnectionPoolLookup` controller service with potentially a very large number of databases – order of 100s – configured with `DBCPConnectionPool` controller services. All of these `DBCPConnectionPool` are configured to hit a different database potentially with different credentials on the *same server* or a very small number of servers – order of 1s.

What are the limiting factors that could necessitate setting up additional NiFi instances, perhaps on a different system (physical or virtual)? It seems that NiFi would be using connection pooling and perhaps close connections that haven't been used "recently" or I speculate that it may have a global connection limit governing this.

There doesn't seem to be a limit on the number of configured `DBCPConnectionPool` services but there *must* be a practical limit based on hardware resources. I'm not quite sure of all of the factors that I should include in that calculation.

Short of field testing, how can I estimate a limit on the number of databases a single NiFi instance can handle?

Answer (score 2):

NiFi uses [Apache DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/) to do connection pooling, I would think the limitations are related to that and to the available JVM heap, etc. Recent versions of NiFi can set various user-defined properties that get passed to the DataSource created using the parameters described [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).